# Firefox y Chrome en IPhone/IPad no descarga PDFs

Tags: firefox, chrome, iphone

Estoy intentando descargar ficheros PDF en IPhone/Ipad desde Firefox y Chrome

Cuando aparece la ventana para descargar, al pulsar solo me guarda 4KB. cuando los ficheros tienen mas de 5MB.

Están definidas las siguientes cabeceras

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 15027469
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fichero.pdf'"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
```

Si se realiza la descarga desde Safari, la descarga se realiza correctamente.

Las versiones de Firefox y Chrome están actualizadas a la última versión.

¿Alguna idea de porqué no me descarga en estos navegadores ?

Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir las cabeceras enviadas y recibidas durante la transferencia? Para ello usa el inspector de red del navegador. También nos vendría bien saber qué contenido ha descargado. Aunque sean 4 KiB es posible que haya una pista del motivo por el que ha fallado la descarga en el contenido del archivo. También sería de bastante ayuda el código que genera el envío.

Comment: En Firefox desde Ipad no puedo ver el inspector. Esas son las cabeceras que se envían para la descarga, diferenciando el tamaño para cada fichero. Solo falla en dispositivos IPhone e Ipad con Firefox y Chrome. En W10 funciona correctamente en todos los navegadores. En MAC también y en Android también descarga correctamente el PDF.

Comment: He hecho está pregunta por si es problema de estos navegadores para dispositivos de Apple, por que en el resto de Sistemas si funciona correctamente con estos navegadores

Comment: Prueba cambiando el content-disposition a `inline` para ver qué hace. Y yo no pondría el Expires en 0.

Comment: Disculpa, malentendí la pregunta. Si solo te falla en dispositivos Apple entonces no puedo ayudarte a reproducir el problema. Aunque conociendo las cabeceras exactas sí que podría ayudarte en caso de que alguna estuviera mal o interfiriendo. Deberían comportarse igual que en Android o PC.